# Android - Read and Write file in src/main directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources, src, android-file

I aim to firstly read and then write a file **not accessible for the final user** in the *src/main* folder of the app installation. Because I do not want the user to know about this file, I decided to manually save it here and, at some point of the application usage, I want to read and write from/to there.

- Do you know how can I access this path and read/write it?
- Is it a good idea to create that file there or you advice me to locate the file in another folder?

Comment: There is no "src/main folder of the app installation". An Android app *project* has a `src/main/` directory, but that directory does not exist on the devices. For local storage without direct user access, use [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Internal storage looks appropriate for your purpose:

```
File myfile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "myFile.txt");
```

You can also access it in Android Studio "Device Explorer" as data/data/com.example.myapp.../files/myFile.txt

Comment: Thanks but, how can I add it manually for first time? I mean, I need to attach it manually, not coding